# OpenShift Active Directory Authentication

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am really struggling to get Active Directory authentication to work.

The oauthConfig section of the master-config.yaml file starts out like this and all is fine.

```
oauthConfig:
  assetPublicURL: https://master.domain.local:8443/console/
  grantConfig:
    method: auto
  identityProviders:
  - challenge: true
    login: true
    mappingMethod: claim
    name: allow_all
    provider:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider
  masterCA: ca-bundle.crt
  masterPublicURL: https://master.domain.local:8443
  masterURL: https://master.domain.local:8443
```

Then I attempt to modify the oauthConfig section of the master-config.yaml file to look like this.

```
oauthConfig:
  assetPublicURL: https://master.domain.local:8443/console/
  grantConfig:
    method: auto
  identityProviders:
  - name: Active_Directory
    challenge: true
    login: true
    mappingMethod: claim
    provider:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: LDAPPasswordIdentityProvider
      attributes:
        id:
        - dn
        email:
        - mail
        name:
        - cn
        preferredUsername:
        - uid
      bindDN: "cn=openshift,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local"
      bindPassword: "password"
      insecure: true
      url: ldap://dc.domain.local:389/cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local?uid
  assetPublicURL: https://master.domain.local:8443/console/
  masterPublicURL: https://master.domain.local:8443
  masterURL: https://master.domain.local:8443
```

Then I try to restart the origin-master service and it fails to restart, and won't start again, not even on reboot. If I revert back to the old master-config.yaml file everything works fine again, and origin-master service starts with no problem.

The user "openshift" has been created in Active Directory with the correct password.

I have even tried using 
url: ldaps://dc.domain.local:686/cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local?uid

That doesn't work either. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong and what the origin-master service does not like about the modified master-config.yaml file that keeps it from starting.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? /var/log/messages on rhel based systems usually.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding back `masterCA`, `sessionConfig` and `tokenConfig`, and removing the duplicate `assetPublicURL`.  Adjust the `sessionSecretesFile` path as needed.

```
  masterCA: ca-bundle.crt
  sessionConfig:
    sessionMaxAgeSeconds: 3600
    sessionName: ssn
    sessionSecretsFile: /etc/origin/master/session-secrets.yaml
  tokenConfig:
    accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds: 86400
    authorizeTokenMaxAgeSeconds: 500
```